# How to handle the screenshots when use rebot tool

Tags: automation, robotframework

I want to use rebot tool to merge some test suites'results. But I have no idea to handle the screenshots in the integrated report. The timeout screenshots' names in each test suite are the same（like selenium-screenshots-(1).png....)
Can you help me

Answer (score 1):

You can find the module '_ScreenshotKeywords' and replace the code

```
    def _get_screenshot_paths(self, filename):
        if not filename:
#            self._screenshot_index += 1
            from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
            variables = BuiltIn().get_variables()
            test=variables['${TEST NAME}']
            testsuite=variables['${SUITE NAME}']
            file= testsuite+"."+test
            filename = 'selenium-screenshot-%s.png' % file
        else:
            filename = filename.replace('/', os.sep)
        logdir = self._get_log_dir()
        path = os.path.join(logdir, filename)
        link = robot.utils.get_link_path(path, logdir)
        return path, link
```